# How to display total record count against models in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Is there a neat way to make the record/object count for a model appear on the main model list in the django admin module?

I have found techniques for showing counts of related objects within sets in the list_display page (and I can see the total in the pagination section at the bottom of the same), but haven't come across a neat way to show the record count at the model list level.

Comment: Do you want to get number of ALL registered models in django admin?

Comment: Not necessarily. There's one in particular I'm interested in.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you finally resolve your problem?

Comment: I didn't, managed without it in the end.

Answer (score 3):

I would look into the models.Manager class. A subclass of Manager will allow you to add table-level functionality to your models. A Manager method can return any data you want and there is an interesting example in the [Django DB API documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/). You may then be able to pull this into Admin by adding a admin inner class to your model.

Answer (score 3):

```
from django import template
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def get_model_count(admin_url):
  app_label, model_name = admin_url.split('/')[:2]
  return get_model(app_label, model_name, seed_cache=False).objects.count()
```

Then copy and override "/templates/admin/index.html" from "django's contrib/admin/templates/index.html".

At the top add:

```
{% load NAME_OF_YOUR_TAG_FILE %}
```

Add the following call after the model name or wherever:

```
{% get_model_count model.admin_url %}
```

This fits nicely into this use case. You're done!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any nice way to add count of models in the main admin page, but here is the solution that I finally use.

In short I compute the counts of each models in signals post_delete and post_save methods, store the variables in the custom request (in a map) and display it in the extended admin index.html by simply checking with an if for each desired models.

The extended *templates/admin/index.html*:

```
{% if model.perms.change %}
    <th scope="row"><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">{{ model.name }} 
    {% if model.name == "Mymodel1_verbose_name_plural" %} ({{ MODELS_COUNT.Mymodel1}}) {% endif %}
    </a></th>
{% else %}
```

My custom request in util/context_processors.py:

```
from myproject import settings

def myproject(request):
    return {
        'request' : request,
        'MODELS_COUNT' : settings.MODELS_COUNT
    }
```

In my *settings.py*:

```
MODELS_COUNT = {
      'Mymodel1': None,
      'Mymodel2': None       
}

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'myproject.util.context_processors.myproject',
)
```

In *myproject.__init__.py*:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete

def save_mymodel1_count(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        settings.MODELS_COUNT['Mymodel1'] = Mymodel1.objects.count()
def delete_mymodel1_count(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    settings.MODELS_COUNT['Mymodel1'] = Mymodel1.objects.count()
settings.MODELS_COUNT['Mymodel1'] = Mymodel1.objects.count()

post_save.connect(save_mymodel1_count, sender=Mymodel1)
post_delete.connect(delete_mymodel1_count, sender=Mymodel1)
```

If you have lots of models, I suggest that you transform this in a more generic solution.